# how to give color to a video in binary form

Tags: python, video-processing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
ret,im = cap.read()
key = cv2.waitKey(10)
cv2.imshow('frametest',im)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,th = cv2.threshold(gray,255,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('videotest',th)

if key == 27:
    break
```

This is a part of my code where am converting a gray image to binary. I need to color the  binarized video.Can anyone suggest any method in doing so.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "color the binarized video"? Can you show example picture for "colored binarized video"?